# JQuery DataTable Cell from a row click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to implement a function on jquery datatable, that returns the 1st and the 4th column of a clicked row

i am following this example, which allows me to manipulate a clicked row
http://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html

thinking that i can change this handler to do the read cell value procedures and use the value on my own logic

```
/* Add a click handler to the rows - this could be used as a callback */
$("#example tbody").click(function(event) {
    $(oTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function (){
        $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
    });
    $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
});
```

i have also come over with this little code segment from dataTable forum http://datatables.net/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=1384&page=1#Item_0

```
$('#example tbody tr').click( function () {
    // Alert the contents of an element in a SPAN in the first TD
    alert( $('td:eq(0) span', this).html() );
} );
```

may i have any pointer so i can get the 1st and 4th column of the clicked field?

**next part**
I have the above solved, thanks nick

however i have the next part of the problem. when i init the table 
i use

```
/* Init the table */
    oTable = $('#filetable').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/crvWeb/jsonFileList.do",
        "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
            $.ajax( {
                "dataType": 'json', 
                "type": "POST", 
                "url": sSource, 
                "data": aoData, 
                "success": fnCallback
            } );
        }
    } );
```

my servlet takes a dir request parameter and returns a listing to the datatable as json response.

```
/crvWeb/jsonFileList.do
```

how can i add and get serlvet response with post request so i can have my table updated?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) easiest here, like this:

```
$("#example tbody").delegate("tr", "click", function() {
  var firstCellText = $("td:first", this).text();
  var fourthCellText = $("td:eq(3)", this).text();
});
```

[You can try out a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/5kJW3/)

With [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) `this` refers to the `<tr>` since that's the click we're handling, making things quite a bit cleaner..and it's still only one event handler at the `<tbody>` level, not one per `<tr>`.

Comment: one more follow up question. if i would like to pass the value into the grid to update it, how i should do it to use the funtion of post to update the table on the fly ?

Comment: @nokheat - How do you mean? If you can describe a bit more about where the values comes from and goes I might be able to help...I have to crash for the night, but reply here and I'll check it in the morning :)

Comment: i need to show some code segment so please refer to my newly edit

Comment: @nokheat - Please take what you added and form a new question with it, since that's a totally different topic...it's better for a question/answer to be about one thing, it helps future googlers finding this better :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, if I'm reading your code correctly:

```
$("tr.row_selected td:nth-child(1), tr.row_selected td:nth-child(4)");
```

It should return the first and fourth child of all tr elements with the class `row_selected`.

Comment: i am checking my code and your solution however i am still trying to work around it . the main convern is, can i really take a reference from the handler input ? like $("#example tbody"), and use the this identifier to get the reference of the cell and hence its value?