# Using jQuery in table to display single cell contents of selected row outside of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

This is essentially my table inside of a loop:

```
<table id="tblMyTable">
  <tr>
     <td><%= attachment.Name %></td>
     <td><%= attachment.Description %></td>
     <td>
        <a id="clickPreview" href="#">Preview</a>
        <div id="divAttachmentContents" style="display:none;"> <%= attachment.ContentsAsHtml %>
        </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

From this I get multiple rows with data.  I want to have a preview button on the end of the row, the last column, that will 'preview' the contents in a div further down the page.
I assumed I should render out the content to a hidden cell to make it appear quickly.

I need to know how to tell jQuery the row I'm on - and to fetch the text of the last cell.

The gist of what I need is:

```
    $('#clickPreview').click(function () {
        var newContent = $('#divAttachmentContents').text();
        $('#divAttachmentPreview').html(newContent);
    });
```

But that only works on the first row.
I may have to do something like

```
<div id="<%= "divAttachmentContents_" + attachment.Id %>" style="display:none;"> <%= attachment.ContentsAsHtml %> </div>
```

But I'm not sure.  This may be similar to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185391/jquery-datatable-cell-from-a-row-click) Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suggest not using IDs if you have many rows.

Comment: true - I wasn't thinking...thanks for the point.  I will have many rows, which is why this is a challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a class for the anchor. That will make the job easier. For e.g.

```
$('.clickPreviewClass').click(function () {
    var newContent =$(this).next("div").text();
    $('#divAttachmentPreview').html(newContent);
});
```

assuming `clickPreviewClass` is the name of the class you give your anchor.

Comment: ended up using
$('.clickPreview').click(function () {
  var newContent = $(this).next(".divAttachmentContents").text();
  $('#divAttachmentPreview').html(newContent);
});

and adding classes instead of ID's.  Thanks for the clarification.